# how to create a pivot table with the count of text

Tags: r

im working with pivot tables on r and i´ve been trying to do something but i cant.
i have something like this:

[tb1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Geb.jpg)

```
ESM     tipo_Entrega
name1   acuerdo
name1   no_acuerdo
name2   acuerdo
name2   acuerdo
name3   no_acuerdo
name3   acuerdo
```

and i need the table to be like this:
[tb2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke1ir.jpg)

```
esm    acuerdo  no_acuerdo
name1     1          1
name2     2          0
name3     1          1
```

ive been using `dplyr` and i did this:

```
pvt1 <- rpen %>% group_by(ESM,Tipo.Entrega) %>% summarise(Count = n())
```

the result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d33p0.png)

```
esm    tipo.entrega   count
name1   acuerdo         1
name1   no_acuerdo      1
name2   acuerdo         2
name2   no_acuerdo      0
name3   acuerdo         1
name3   no_acuerdo      1
```

i also try this:

```
pvt1 <- rpen[ , c(9,25)]
pvt1 <- mutate(pvt1 ,  Acu = ifelse(tdcondes$Tipo.Entrega=="ACUERDO", "1", "0"))
pvt1 <- mutate(pvt1 ,  No_Acu = ifelse(tdcondes$Tipo.Entrega=="NO ACUERDO", "1", "0"))
pvt1 <- pvt1 [ , c(1,3:4)]

pvt1 <- pvt1 %>% group_by(ESM) %>% summarise(Acu = sum(Acu), No_Acu = sum(No_Acu))
```

and i got this error:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `Acu`.
x 'type' (character) de argumento no válido
i Input `Acu` is `sum(Acu)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: ESM = "1006 - BATALLÓN DE INFANTERÍA MECANIZADO NO 05 \"GENERAL JOSE MARIA CORDOVA".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

then i try to use the package `pivottabler` and i got the result i want but the first column has no name and i need to compare this info with another and without name in the first column its not posible...
i dont know what to do... help please!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98ux6.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ESM,     ~tipo_Entrega,
"name1",    "acuerdo",
"name1",    "no_acuerdo",
"name2",    "acuerdo",
"name2",    "acuerdo",
"name3",    "no_acuerdo",
"name3",    "acuerdo")

dat %>% 
  group_by(tipo_Entrega, ESM) %>% 
  summarise(n=n()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="tipo_Entrega", values_from="n", values_fill=0)
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   ESM   acuerdo no_acuerdo
#   <chr>   <int>      <int>
# 1 name1       1          1
# 2 name2       2          0
# 3 name3       1          1
```

Comment: wow, thanks for answering so fast, this one works for me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A base R option with `table` + `reshape`

```
reshape(
  data.frame(table(df)),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "ESM",
  timevar = "tipo_Entrega"
)
```

gives

```
    ESM Freq.acuerdo Freq.no_acuerdo
1 name1            1               1
2 name2            2               0
3 name3            1               1
```

---

A `data.table` option with `dcast`

```
dcast(setDT(df), ESM ~ tipo_Entrega)
```

gives

```
     ESM acuerdo no_acuerdo
1: name1       1          1
2: name2       2          0
3: name3       1          1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all using `pivot_wider` from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = ESM,
                     names_from = tipo_Entrega,
                     values_from = tipo_Entrega,
                     values_fn = length,
                     values_fill = 0)
```

If you don't want `ESM` in your final dataset you can always pipe (`%>%`) the output of this to `dplyr::select(-ESM)`.

---

**Output**

```
 ESM   acuerdo no_acuerdo
  <chr>   <int>      <int>
1 name1       1          1
2 name2       2          0
3 name3       1          1
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ESM = c("name1", "name1", "name2", "name2", "name3", 
                             "name3"), tipo_Entrega = c("acuerdo", "no_acuerdo", "acuerdo", 
                                                        "acuerdo", "no_acuerdo", "acuerdo")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                  -6L))
```